# is the dependence of approximate entropy on the length of compared runs just bias or an evidence that implies different information in the time series

Tags: entropy

Approximate entropy is heavily dependent on the length of time series ($L$), the length of compared runs ($m$) which is generally set to 2, and the criterion of similarity ($r$).

Definition of approximate entropy：

(1) Fix $m$, a positive integer, and r, a positive real number. 
Given a time-series of data $u(1),u(2),...,u(n)$, from measurements equally spaced in time.

(2)Form a sequence of vectors $x(1),x(2),...,x(N-m+1)$ defined by $x(i) = [u(i),u(i+1),...,u(i+m-1)]$.

(3)Next, defined for each $i,1<=i<=N-m+1, C_i^m(r) = $ (number of $j$ such that $d[x(i),x(j)<=r)/(N-m+1)]$. With $d[x(i),x(j)] = max_{k=1,2,...,m}(|u(i+k-1)-u(j+k-1)|)$.

(4)From  $C_i^m(r)$, define $C^m(r)=(N-m-1)^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^{N-m+1}C_i^m(r)$

(5)Define $\Phi^m(r)=(N-m-1)^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^{N-m+1}logC_i^m(r)$

(6)Fix $m$ and $r$, define approximate entropy, $ApEn(m,r)=\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty}[\Phi^m(r)-\Phi^{m+1}(r)]$

(7)When given N data points, we implement this formula by defining the statistic
$ApEn(m,r,N)=\Phi^m(r)-\Phi^{m+1}(r)$

My first question: Does the value of approximate entropy only contain a limited part of information in the time series when m is set to 2 ? So I'll get new information from new value of approximate entropy when m equals 3 and L & r keep unchanged? Does this make any sense?

My second question: Can I get new information when changing r values with other parameters unchanged? Does this make any sense too?

My third question: how long on earth does a time series need to be when calculating approximate entropy? Pincus(1991) said at least 1000 sample points, while Pincus (1995) said more than 100 points. See
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC51218/pdf/pnas01056-0271.pdf and  http://aip.scitation.org/doi/abs/10.1063/1.166092

I'll be grateful for any answer! Thank you!

Comment: Please include a formula defining approximate entropy in the question.

Comment: @kodlu I've add the definition in it. Thank you for your advice.